# Spree admin user interface not displaying all options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, spree

I have created a spree site with rails. However the admin wont display mail or image settings? I was wondering if anyone could give me any guidance as to why and how to resolve?

Thanks

Gemfile with relevant spree info is below:

```
gem 'spree', '2.3.2'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-3-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-3-stable'
gem 'spree_bootstrap_frontend', github: '200Creative/spree_bootstrap_frontend', branch: '2-3-stable'

gem 'aws-sdk'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spree has extracted the mail settings out into a gem now I believe. It now works by reading your regular rails action mailer settings, usually set in an initializer or environment file.

If you want the legacy mail settings back, you can checkout https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings